# Dar forma a un LinearLayout con gradiente

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Tengo el siguiente código que genera un gradiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="#2e3192"
                android:endColor="#00ffe9"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Y este otro xml de un layout que en un linerlayout toma ese gradient y lo usa de background color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ForgotPassword">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/azure"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_color"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Mi consulta es, como puedo modificar ese xml o el linerlayout para lograr lo que muestro en la imagen de la derecha (Actualmente tengo lo que se muestra en la de la izquierda)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas un `layer-list` para agregar la figura con el gradiente y aplicar una rotación o agregar otra figura para que de la impresión que deseas, esta es tu imagen original :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una opción es rotar la figura para obtener un efecto similar al que deseas:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="200dp"
        android:bottom="-100dp"
        android:right="-400dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-10"
            android:pivotY="200%">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient
                    android:angle="-45"
                    android:startColor="#2e3192"
                    android:endColor="#00ffe9"
                    android:type="linear" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

de esta forma obtendrías:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me parece que **lo ideal para conservar el gradiente de los colores es agregar un triangulo de color blanco además de tu gradiente con un angulo de 70 grados**, de esta forma obtendrías el efecto que muestras en tu pregunta, este sería el `layer-list`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="#2e3192"
                android:endColor="#00ffe9"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="70"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="-60dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

para obtener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo del triangulo blanco funciona perfecto, muchas gracias!

Comment: @Juan Creo que es lo ideal para obtener el degradado que muestras en tu pregunta, un placer ayudarte, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Una solución puede ser la siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="300dp"
    android:bottom="-300dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="-300dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-20"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="100%">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:startColor="#2e3192"
                android:endColor="#00ffe9"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```